# Spring POST request with relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have two entity types in Spring with a relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Domain {

  public Domain() {}

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String image;

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Subdomain.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="domain_id")
  private Set<Subdomain> subdomain = new HashSet<>();

  //Default getters and setters

  }
```

And the type subdomain:

```
@Entity
public class Subdomain {

  public Subdomain() {}

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id", nullable = false)
  public Domain domain;

  //Default getters and setters
}
```

This works perfect with a get request, the relation is fetched. But how does it works with post request? I would create a new subdomain with the relationship to an existing domain:

```
"domain_id": "2"
```

And this:

```
"domain_id": "http://localhost/subdomain/2"
```

But this doesn't work. What is the best way to solve this?

```
Could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested       exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: you have to fetch the subdomain from DB and add this to the maindomian object and save

Comment: Yeah but how can i fetch the domain in the controller? What is the best way to do? Thanks anyway

Comment: What does POST / GET requests have to do with plain data?

Comment: Start by fixing your mapping. It's incorrect. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional. Now, to create a subdomain for a given domain, you would send the data of the subdomain, and the ID of its parent domain, you would then get the Domain identified by this parent domain ID using its repository, create a SubDomain, and persist it (and/or simply add it to the parent domain's set of domains, since that will persist the subdomain thanks to the cascade option you configured)..